# Proving this subgroup/cyclic property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Wondering how to do the later parts and if my attempts are correct so far.

### Question

1. Show that if $G$ is a group, and $a \in G$, then $H = \{a^k |k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
2. Show that if the subgroup $H$ in part $1$ is finite, then there exists positive integer $m$ such that $$a^m = e \quad \text{and} \quad H = \{e,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{m-1}\}.$$
3. If $G$ is a finite group and $|G|$ is prime, then is $G$ cyclic. Prove it.
4. Let $p$ be prime and suppose $|G| = |H| = p$. Prove that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

### My attempts

1. Since $H$ is clearly a non-empty subset of $G$ then we check closure and inverse axiom. Let $\star$ be the operation of $G$.
   Let $x,y\in H$ then $x=a^k$ and $y =a^l$ for some $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$.
   $x\star y = a^k \star a^l$...... Does this simplify to $a^{k\star l}$ or $a^{k+l}$?
2. Since $H$ is finite, then since $H$ is a subgroup, it contains an inverse element $e$. Let $e = a^n$ for some integer $n$. Then let $a \in H \implies e\star a = a^{n\star 1}$.
   I'm not sure how to really continue because "logically" I feel since it's finite, it should cycle over again I just can't put this down as a mathematical proof.
3. I have no clue. I feel like it's a yes, because we prove that $H$ is cyclic, and we didn't even restrict the prime condition on $H$. But again, I'm not sure how to mathematically prove.
4. Unsure how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Next time, ask a new question for your each question.

Comment: There is a simple rule for proving that a non-empty set $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup. For that it is enough to show that $a,b\in H\implies ab^{-1}\in H$. If $a\in H$ (note that $H$ is demanded to be non-empty) then $e=aa^{-1}\in H$. Then $a^{-1}=ea^{-1}\in H$. Finally if $a,b\in H$ then $ab=a(b^{-1})^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 2, you have the right intuition, but:

- $e$ is not 'an inverse element' but 'the neutral element'.
- You need to find $e=a^n$ **for $n>0$**, since obviouly $e=a^0$ and that doesn't require the group to be finite.
- Once you have $e=a^n$, you can take any $x=a^p \in H$ and show that $x=a^r$ for some $r, 0<=r<n$. (Hint: euclidean division...)

Question 3, take an element $a\neq e$ in H, and consider $A=\{a^n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ If there is $b\in H-A$, what can you say about $ba$. About $ba^2$ ?

Question 4, use question 3 to write both groups as cyclic groups...

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt, $k, l$ are just integers, so $k \star l$ is meaningless because the operation is defined on $G$, not on integers.Plus, to show that it is a subgroup, you have to state also that $a^0 = e \in H$ before saying that it is nonempty.

Addition to that, by definition, $a^k \star a^l = a^{k+l}$ for any multiplicative operation $\star$.

For the second question:

Let $|H| = m$.If we can show that all the elements in the set $S = \{e, a,...,a^{m-1}\}$ are distinct, we can say that $ S = H $.

For the third question;

Hint: Let $a \in G$. Is the cyclic set generated by $a$ a subgroup of G ? If so, by Lagrange Theorem, what can you concluded that considering the order of G is prime ?

For the forth question;

Hint: Let $f : G \to H$ defined by $g \to h$, where $<g> = G$ and $<h> = H$.